# I sometimes see that people wrap json_encode() in htmlspecialchars(). Why?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I usually do this:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

But I see that people sometimes do this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES );
```

Why would you use htmlspecialchars on JSON?

Comment: JSON_HEX_TAG, JSON_HEX_APOS, JSON_HEX_AMP, and JSON_HEX_QUOT can be used since PHP 5.3. http://www.php.net/manual/json.constants.php

Comment: Symfony's JsonResponse is the one of real world examples for these options: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php#L89-L95

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know php, so i'll assume htmlspecialchars escapes any html special characters.

Given that assumption then the use case is planting json data directly inside html content, a la

```
echo "<script>"
echo json_encode($result)
echo "</script>"
```

Given json encoding only encodes content to avoid escaping from the JS parser, this scenario would allow someone to insert JSON data that the html parser interpreted as ending the script tag.

Something like

```
{"foo": "</script><script>doSomethingEvil()</script>"}
```

would then reach the browser as

```
<script>{"foo": "</script><script>doSomethingEvil()</script>"}<script>
```

Which clearly results in doSomethingEvil() being executed.  By escaping any html tokens you end up sending something like

```
<script>{"foo": "&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script&gt;doSomethingEvil()&lt;/script&gt;"}<script>
```

Instead, which avoids the XSS vulnerability.

A far better solution to this problem is to simply not send JSON data directly in an HTML source (JSON encoding just makes the content safe to embed in JS, not HTML)

Comment: A simple string replacement (`</` to `<\/`) would solve that particular issue more efficiently and with fewer side effects.

Comment: It actually encodes it as `{"foo":"<\/script><script>doSomethingEvil()<\/script>"}` (note the escaped slashes). So I think it's safe.

Comment: @Quentin, That's not quite sufficient.  You need to also prevent the JSON from containing [escaping text spans](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/aria/syntax.html#escaping-text-span) which can stop the browser from recognizing the legit script end tag.

Comment: @JW ah, json_encode over-escapes relative to JSON.stringify in ECMAScript (which is spec mandated to not escape /) -- it's conceivable that given it is primarily targeted at browsers json_encode (at least in modern php versions) "over escapes" all potentially unsafe html content.

Answer (score 9):

None of the characters which have special meaning in JSON have special meaning in HTML (except for the quote characters which `ENT_NOQUOTES` explicitly excludes).

It makes the data safe for dumping into HTML documents (so long as it isn't placed inside an attribute value) via `innerHTML`. Naturally, it makes the data unsafe for any purpose that does't involve building markup using strings.

I wouldn't advise doing this (in the general case), escaping should be done at the last possible moment before inserting into the desired data format (to maximise reusability and make it clear where developers should expect to see escaping code).

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure it would also make the data safe for use in an attribute value.

Comment: It wouldn't. The code in the question says `ENT_NOQUOTES` so it would leave quote characters intact. The string delimiters would break attribute values delimited with double quotes. A single quote as data would break attribute values delimited with single quotes.

Comment: Right, I missed the ENT_NOQUOTES.

Answer (score 3):

olliej's answer is excellent, but there is one case they haven't covered.

> Why would you use htmlspecialchars on JSON?

If you are embedding in a script tag in XHTML outside a CDATA section then you should escape XML special characters.  `htmlspecialchars` should work fine for that.

This is a pretty marginal case though so take olliej's advice.